# vsftpd over xinetd: connection refused

Tags: ftp, gentoo, xinetd, vsftpd

I've been banging my head against this for hours and I'm stumped.  I am setting up a Gentoo Linux box with vsftpd.  I can get it to work as a standalone daemon, but not with xinetd.  When I try to connect from another machine, its FTP client says:

```
ftp: Can't connect to 'my.ip.add.ress': Connection refused
ftp: Can't connect to 'my.domain.tld'
```

I've tried everything I can think of.  "enabled = yes", "disabled = no", etc. etc.  I don't believe it's a firewall issue because I was able to make it run via standalone mode.  The OS is fully updated to the "stable" Portage tree.  `/etc/init.d/xinetd` is running, and `/etc/init.d/vsftpd` is not.  The output of `netstat` doesn't include anything about Port 20 or 21, xinetd or ftp.

Nothing in `/var/log/` appears to be recorded when I make a (failed) login attempt.  When I restart xinetd, `/var/log/messages` indicates xinetd reads each file in `/etc/xinetd.d/`, but then it always says `removing ftp` toward the end of its startup phase.

Here's my `/etc/xinetd.conf`:

```
defaults {
    enabled     = yes
    log_type    = SYSLOG daemon info 
    log_on_failure  = HOST
    log_on_success  = PID HOST DURATION EXIT
    only_from   = 0.0.0.0
    cps     = 50 10
    instances   = 50
    per_source  = 10
    v6only      = no
    groups      = yes
    umask       = 002
}
includedir /etc/xinetd.d
```

And here's my `/etc/xinetd.d/vsftpd`:

```
service ftp {
    socket_type     = stream
    wait            = no
    user            = root
    server          = /usr/sbin/vsftpd
    server_args     = /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
    log_on_success  += DURATION
    nice            = 10
    disable         = no
}
```

And here's my `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`:

```
accept_timeout=60
anon_umask=022
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
anon_other_write_enable=YES
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_world_readable_only=NO
anonymous_enable=NO
banner_file=/etc/motd
chroot_local_user=YES
connect_timeout=60
data_connection_timeout=300
guest_enable=YES
guest_username=admin
hide_ids=YES
idle_session_timeout=900
listen=NO
local_enable=YES
local_root=/home/admin/uploads
log_ftp_protocol=YES
ls_recurse_enable=NO
pam_service_name=/etc/pam.d/vsftpd
userlist_deny=NO
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd/users.allow
write_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Nothing in your post mentions a firewall, is iptables running?

Comment: There is no firewall on the server (yet).  I was able to make it work in standalone mode, so I wouldn't think that's the issue, unless xinetd needs something more configured in relation to ports and all.

Comment: You can run xinetd in debug mode (with `-d`) to get verbose output about what it's doing.  This might help identify your problem.

Comment: What version of vsftpd are you running?  The source for it was recently hacked and placed for public download; it could be your version is compromised and as such, may have a bug or two in it. ( see http://www.thehackernews.com/2011/07/video-demonstration-vsftpd-backdoor.html )

Comment: Doh!  I figured it out myself.  I read the man page on `xinetd.conf` and realized the `enabled` option is supposed to be a list of services to enable, rather than boolean YES or NO.  I commented out that option and it fired up just fine.  Hours down the tubes... grrr.  I would have posted this as an answer to my own question but it won't met me for another 8 hours.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my comment above, I figured it out myself.  In 'xinetd.conf', the `enabled` option is NOT a boolean.  If present, it should be a list of services to enable.  Commenting it out worked for me.